# comparing two text file and find out the related word in python

Tags: python

i am having two text file named search.txt and log.txt which contain some data like below.

**search.txt**

```
19:00:15  , mouse , FALSE
19:00:15  , branded luggage bags and trolley , TRUE
19:00:15  , Leather shoes for men , FALSE
19:00:15  , printers , TRUE
19:00:16  , adidas watches for men , TRUE
19:00:16  , Mobile Charger Stand/Holder black , FALSE
19:00:16  , watches for men , TRUE
```

**log.txt**

```
19:00:00 ,  trakjkfsa,
19:00:00 ,  door,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  sweater,
19:00:00 ,  dis,
19:00:01 ,  not,
19:00:01 ,  nokia,
19:00:01 ,  collar,
19:00:01 ,  nokia,
19:00:01 ,  collar,
19:00:01 ,  gsm,
19:00:01 ,  sweater,
19:00:01 ,  sweater,
19:00:01 ,  gsm,
19:00:02 ,  gsm,
19:00:02 ,  show,
19:00:02 ,  wayfreyerv,
19:00:02 ,  door,
19:00:02 ,  collar,
19:00:02 ,  or,
19:00:02 ,  harman,
19:00:02 ,  women's,
19:00:02 ,  collar,
19:00:02 ,  sweater,
19:00:02 ,  head,
19:00:03 ,  womanw,
19:00:03 ,  com.shopclues.utils.k@42233ff0,
19:00:03 ,  samsu,
19:00:03 ,  adidas,
19:00:03 ,  collar,
19:00:04 ,  ambas,
19:00:04 ,  harman,
19:00:04 ,  mi,
19:00:04 ,  nor,
19:00:04 ,  airtel,
19:00:04 ,  ,
19:00:04 ,  adidas,
19:00:05 ,  harman,
19:00:05 ,  collar,
19:00:05 ,  flip,
19:00:05 ,  brass,
19:00:05 ,  laptop,
19:00:05 ,  collar,
19:00:05 ,  wayfreyer,
19:00:05 ,  head,
19:00:05 ,  adidas,
19:00:05 ,  discn,
19:00:05 ,  head,
19:00:05 ,  adidas,
19:00:05 ,  collar,
19:00:05 ,  collar,
19:00:06 ,  disco,
19:00:06 ,  head,
19:00:06 ,  harman,
19:00:06 ,  nigh,
19:00:06 ,  microsoft,
19:00:06 ,  ambassado,
19:00:07 ,  salwar,
19:00:07 ,  bb,
19:00:07 ,  harman,
19:00:07 ,  ambassador,
19:00:07 ,  ambassador,
19:00:07 ,  salwar,
19:00:08 ,  microsoft,
19:00:08 ,  ac,
19:00:08 ,  jea,
19:00:08 ,  gens, 
19:00:08 ,  ambassador,
19:00:08 ,  orpa,
19:00:09 ,  ac,
19:00:09 ,  black,
19:00:09 ,  asus,
19:00:09 ,  salwar,
19:00:09 ,  salwar,
19:00:09 ,  ac,
19:00:10 ,  whechains,
19:00:10 ,  gens,
19:00:10 ,  ambassador,
19:00:10 ,  sony,
19:00:10 ,  salwa,
19:00:10 ,  ac,
19:00:10 ,  woman,
19:00:10 ,  li,
19:00:11 ,  boxers,
19:00:11 ,  harman,
19:00:11 ,  sal,
19:00:11 ,  ambassador,
19:00:11 ,  sony, 
19:00:11 ,  ,
19:00:11 ,  boxers,
19:00:12 ,  adidas,
19:00:12 ,  samsung,
19:00:12 ,  boxer,
19:00:12 ,  boxers,
19:00:12 ,  com.shopclues.utils.k@427b9538,
19:00:12 ,  harman,
19:00:12 ,  wechains#002,
19:00:12 ,  collar,
19:00:13 ,  collar,
19:00:13 ,  collar,
19:00:13 ,  one,
19:00:13 ,  collar,
19:00:13 ,  ambassador,
19:00:13 ,  hitech,
19:00:13 ,  fanc,
19:00:13 ,  adidas,
19:00:13 ,  bp,
19:00:13 ,  asus,
19:00:13 ,  ambassador,
19:00:13 ,  harman,
19:00:14 ,  lin,
19:00:14 ,  one,
19:00:14 ,  samsung,
19:00:14 ,  cond,
19:00:14 ,  atx,
19:00:15 ,  blackles#002,
19:00:15 ,  woman,
19:00:15 ,  asus,
19:00:15 ,  airtel,
19:00:15 ,  weel,
19:00:15 ,  aenglish,
19:00:15 ,  orpat,
19:00:15 ,  one,
19:00:15 ,  condom,
19:00:15 ,  one,
19:00:15 ,  ling,
19:00:15 ,  fancy,
19:00:15 ,  orpat,
19:00:15 ,  woman,
19:00:19 , watches fo,
```

from this what i need to do is , i have to open two files and from the search file if first query selected from search.txt then, it will go to log.txt and search for any query related to that query between :60 sec before and after . if its finding any thing related to search query then it will store the data with a list and append with the search.txt.

o/p should look like this:-

**search.txt**

```
19:00:15  , mouse , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , branded luggage bags and trolley , TRUE - []
19:00:15  , Leather shoes for men , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , printers , TRUE - []
19:00:16  , adidas watches for men , TRUE - [adidas,adidas,adidas,adidas,adidas,adidas]
19:00:16  , Mobile Charger Stand/Holder black , FALSE - []
19:00:16  , watches for men , TRUE
```

let's take an example :
 if "mouse" is the query which placed at "19:00:15" from search.txt then it need to go to the log.txt and find the query related to the the "mouse" in between time of "18:59:15 - 19:01:15 " means 60 sec before and after to the search.txt if any query related to it then it will store the data in search.txt on that line with a list.

below is the code:

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

def getting_partial_queries(querylist):
     basequery = ' '.join(querylist)                
     querylist = []
     for n in range(2,len(basequery)+1):   
         querylist.append(basequery[:n])
     return querylist
queries_time = defaultdict(list)  
with open('logs.txt') as f:            
   for line in f:
      fields = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(',') ]  
      timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%H:%M:%S") 
      queries_time[fields[1]].append(timestamp)  
with open('search.txt') as inputf, open('search_output.txt', 'w') as outputf:
 for line in inputf:
    fields = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(',') ]   
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%H:%M:%S") 
    queries = getting_partial_queries(fields[1].split()) 
    results = []
    for q in queries:
        poss_timestamps = queries_time[q] 
        for ts in poss_timestamps:
            if timestamp - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) <= ts <= timestamp:
                results.append(q)   
            if timestamp + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) >= ts >= timestamp:
                results.append(q)   
    outputf.write (line.strip() + " , {}\n".format(results))
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i have asked that.i need to get the o/p like above by using these 2 inputs.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site where you post questions about a problem you are having, not a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: actually i just need some guide to overcome it.

Comment: Overcome what? What **specific problem** do you need help with?

Comment: i have written the code. now can you help me to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is still unclear what you mean by a "partial query", the code below can do that, simply by you redefining a partial query in the function `filter_out_common_queries`. E.g. if you are looking for an exact match of the query in `search.txt`, you could replace `# add your logic here` by `return [' '.join(querylist), ]`.

```
import datetime as dt
from collections import defaultdict

def filter_out_common_queries(querylist):
    # add your logic here
    return querylist

queries_time = defaultdict(list)  # personally, I'd use 'set' as the default factory
with open('log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(',') ]
        timestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%H:%M:%S")
        queries_time[fields[1]].append(timestamp)  

with open('search.txt') as inputf, open('search_output.txt', 'w') as outputf:
    for line in inputf:
        fields = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(',') ]
        timestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%H:%M:%S")
        queries = filter_out_common_queries(fields[1].split())  # "adidas watches for men" -> "adidas" "watches" "for" "men". "for" is a very generic keyword. You should do well to filter these out
        results = []
        for q in queries:
            poss_timestamps = queries_time[q]
            for ts in poss_timestamps:
                if timestamp - dt.timedelta(seconds=15) <= ts <= timestamp:
                    results.append(q)
        outputf.write(line.strip() + " - {}\n".format(results))
```

Output based on your input data:

```
19:00:15  , mouse , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , branded luggage bags and trolley , TRUE - []
19:00:15  , Leather shoes for men , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , printers , TRUE - []
19:00:16  , adidas watches for men , TRUE - ['adidas', 'adidas', 'adidas', 'adidas', 'adidas', 'adidas']
19:00:16  , Mobile Charger Stand/Holder black , FALSE - ['black']
19:00:16  , watches for men , TRUE - []
```

Remark that a match for 'black' in "Mobile Charger Stand/Holder black" was found. That's because in the code above, I looked for each separate word in itself.

Edit: To implement your comment, you would redefine `filter_out_common_queries` like so:

```
def filter_out_common_queries(querylist):
    basequery = ' '.join(querylist)
    querylist = []
    for n in range(2,len(basequery)+1):
        querylist.append(basequery[:n])
    return querylist
```

Comment: W.i need it check for partial query like below "adidas watches for men" then it can be "ad" "adi" "adid" .... till "adidas watches for men" it should always start with first two letter of the query.

Comment: @s_m That's obvious: the code above is comparing each partial match. It could be improved by only checking the bigger string sequences if the previous sequences matched. Example: if "adi" matched, then "adid" should be checked too, otherwise it shouldn't. But this is not a code writing service. You should try to implement that yourself and then ask for help if it doesn't work out.

Comment: as each query of search file coming in just 1 sec time frequency.
what i am thinking is for each search query we are finding 15 second time before of the search query
in log file.but for next search query again we are finding 15 second time before of the search query
in log file. that is why it is taking more time. but i think when we are getting the second query we need 
not to find again the 15 second before. we can just make 1 sec slide down of the log file. so it will not take more time.
are you getting what i am trying to explain. it will work or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. Read `log.txt` file and get all keywords count from this file by using `split()` method and `collections` module. Target second word of each line of the log file.
2. Now we have all keywords with counter.
3. Read `search.txt` file by line.
4. Get target word from the each line i.e. second word by split by `,`.
5. Use `filter` and `lambda`  to searched keywords form the selected text(4)
6. Get Count value from our dictionary and use string formatting and join method to create new line according to requirement.
7. Write create line into new file.

Code:

```
p1 = "/home/infogrid/Desktop/search.txt"
p2 = "/home/infogrid/Desktop/log.txt"
p3 = "/home/infogrid/Desktop/search_output.txt"

from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()
with open(p2, "rb") as fp:
    for i in fp.readlines():
        cnt[(i.split(",")[1].strip())] += 1
search_keys = cnt.keys()

with open(p1, "rb") as fp:
    with open(p3,"wb") as fp3:
        for i in fp.readlines():
            i = i.strip()
            tmp = i.split(",")[1].strip()
            tmp1 = filter(lambda x: x in tmp, search_keys)
            fp3.write("%s - [%s]\n"%\
                      (i, ",".join([",".join([j]*cnt[j]) for j in tmp1])))
```

Output:

```
19:00:15  , mouse , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , branded luggage bags and trolley , TRUE - []
19:00:15  , Leather shoes for men , FALSE - []
19:00:15  , printers , TRUE - []
19:00:16  , adidas watches for men , TRUE - [adidas,adidas,adidas,adidas,adidas]
19:00:16  , Mobile Charger Stand/Holder black , FALSE - []
19:00:16  , watches for men , TRUE - []
```

**Note:**
Try your self first.

Comment: not in this way.  if the query is 19:00:16  , watches for men , TRUE.. i need to find the partial query of "watches for men" between 19:00:01 - 19:00:16 in "log.txt" file. if we will get any partial query between that time. then we will put that in the list.